# My .min files are not working in Rails 4.1 at all

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Why is this the case for both my CSS and JS files?

For example, bootstrap.css works but not bootstrap.min.css.

It does not matter if I call bootstrap.min.css in my application.css file, or render it separately in my html.erb page with the stylesheet_link_tag. Maybe there is something wrong in my syntax for the stylesheet_link_tag?

EDIT that follows with included code to give proper and full context:

In application.css

```
/*
*= require bootstrap.min
*= require style1
*= require font-awesome.min
*= mystyles.min

*/
```

Some stylesheet_include_tag examples:

```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css" %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :text => "min/css" %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :type => "min/css" %>
```

Comment: I wonder why I was downvoted just for asking questions to problems I am trying to solve. I have no bad intentions and am only concerned with finding solutions when I get stuck. I did search through Google for a while and nothing showed up on StackOverFlow.

Comment: The problem with this question is you're not giving enough context. How do you include these? Can you give specific examples of how these are referenced in your layout and the associated application CSS asset file?

Comment: Well ok, here goes. Suppose I have a MyStyles.min.css file and MyStyles.css file. I also have an application.css file that Rails automatically includes as part of its framework. This application.css file has references to files you want to include, or you can include the css files directly per view page/layout. Nothing I do works. I am not sure what else I was even supposed to add. People who know Rails already know and get what I am saying since it is a pretty basic way assets are used. It seems wrong to be downvoted in this case.

Comment: What's needed here is **code**. For example, what does your `stylesheet_link_tag` call look like? How do you reference this in your `application.css` file?